# Converting an AutoCAD model to a matrix of points/volumes with the mass density specified at each location

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, autocad, g-code

I am an experimental physicist (grad student) that is trying to take an AutoCAD model of the experiment I've built and find the gravitational potential from the whole instrument over a specified volume. Before I find the potential, I'm trying to make a map of the mass density at each point in the model.

What's important is that I already have a model and in the end I'll have a something that says "At (x,y,z) the value is d". If that's an crazy csv file, a numpy array, an excel sheet, or... whatever, I'll be happy.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

Step 1: I color code the AutoCAD file so that color associates with material.

Step 2: I send the new drawing/model to a slicer (made for 3D printing). This takes my 3D object and turns it into equally spaced (in z-direction) 2d objects... but then that's all output as g-code. But hey! G-code is a way of telling a motor how to move.

Step 3: This is the 'hard part' and the meat of this question. I'm thinking that I take that g-code, which is in essence just a set of instructions on how to move a nozzle and use it to populate a numpy array.  Basically I have 3D array, each level corresponds to one position in z, and the grid left is my x-y plane. It reads what color is being put where, and follows the nozzle and puts that mass into those spots. It knows the mass because of the color. It follows the path by parsing the g-code.

When it is done with that level, it moves to the next grid and repeats.

Does this sound insane? Better yet, does it sound plausible?  Or maybe someone has a smarter way of thinking about this.

Even if you just **read** all that, thank you. Seriously.

Comment: Not crazy, but highly non-trivial.  And as currently structured, not a very good fit as a question for stackoverflow.

Comment: It's very reasonable, and can be done - I would argue that it isn't non-trivial - just some work, is all. 

To minimize negative feedback, it may be better to edit your question to something along the lines of: **"Is it possible to translate g-code to obtain a 2D path / cartesian coordinates? If so, how? This is what I'm trying to do... and what I've done, etc. ..."**, since everything else only contributes context.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this sound insane? Better yet, does it sound plausible?

**It's very reasonable and plausible.** Using the g-code could do that, but it would require a g-code interpreter that could map the instructions to a 2D path. (Not 3D, since you mentioned that you're taking fixed z-slices.) That could be problematic, but, if you found one, it could work, but may require some parser manipulation. There are several of these in a variety of languages, that could be useful.

SUGGESTION

**From what you describe, it's akin to doing a MRI scan of the object, and trying to determine its constituent mass profile along a given axis.** In this case, and unlike MRI, you have multiple colors, so that can be used to your advantage in region selection / identification.

**Even if you used a g-code interpreter, it would reproduce an image whose area you'll still have to calculate**, so noting that and given that you seek to determine and classify material composition by path (in that the path defines the boundary of a particular material, which has a unique color), there may be a couple ways to approach this without resorting to g-code:

1) **If the colors of your material are easily (or reasonably) distinguishable, you can create a color mask which will quantify the occupied area, from which you can then determine the mass.**

That is, if you take a photograph of the slice, load the image into a numpy array, and then search for a specific value (say red), you can identify the area of the region. Then, you apply a mask on your array. Once done, you count the occupied elements within your array, and then you divide it by the array size (i.e. rows by columns), which would give you the relative area occupied. Since you know the mass of the material, and there is a constant z-thickness, this will give you the relative mass. An example of color masking using numpy alone is shown here: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/numpy_images.html

As such, let's define an example that's analogous to your problem - let's say we have a picture of a red cabbage, and we want to know which how much of the picture contains red / purple-like pixels.

[image: Red Cabbage]

**To simplify our life, we'll set any pixel above a certain threshold to white (RGB: 255,255,255), and then count how many non-white pixels there are:**

```
from copy import deepcopy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_image(fname, color=128, replacement=(255, 255, 255), plot=False):
    # 128 is a reasonable guess since most of the pixels in the image that have the
    # purplish hue, have RGB's above this value.
    data = imread(fname)
    image_data = deepcopy(data)  # copy the original data (for later use if need be)
    mask = image_data[:, :, 0] < color  # apply the color mask over the image data
    image_data[mask] = np.array(replacement)  # replace the match
    if plot:
        plt.imshow(image_data)
        plt.show()
    return data, image_data

data, image_data = plot_image('cabbage.jpg')  # load the image, and apply the mask

# Find the locations of all the pixels that are non-white (i.e. 255)
# This returns 3 arrays of the same size)
indices = np.where(image_data != 255)

# Now, calculate the area: in this case, ~ 62.04 %
effective_area = indices[0].size / float(data.size)
```

The selected region in question is shown here below:[image: Red Cabbage Pixel Selection]

**Note that `image_data` contains the pixel information that has been masked, and would provide the coordinates (albeit in pixel space) of where each occupied (i.e. non-white) pixel occurs.** *The issue with this of course is that these are pixel coordinates and not a physical one.* But, since you know the physical dimensions, extrapolating those quantities are easily done.

Furthermore, **with the effective area known, and knowledge of the physical dimension, you have a good estimate of the real area occupied.** To obtain better results, tweak the value of the color threshold (i.e. color). In your real-life example, since you know the color, search within a pixel range around that value (to offset noise and lighting issues).

The above method is a bit crude - but effective - and, it may be worth exploring using it in tandem with edge-detection, as that could help improve the region identification, and area selection. (Note that isn't always strictly true!) Also, color deconvolution may be useful: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/color_exposure/plot_ihc_color_separation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-color-exposure-plot-ihc-color-separation-py

The downside to this is that the analysis requires a high quality image, good lighting; and, most importantly, it's likely that you'll lose some of the more finer details of the edges, which would impact your masses.

2) **Instead of resorting to camera work, and given that you have the AutoCAD model, you can use that and the software itself in addition to the above prescribed method.**

Since you've colored each material in the model differently, you can use AutoCAD's slicing tool, and can do something similar to what the first method suggests doing physically: slicing the model, and taking pictures of the slice to expose the surface. Then, using a similar method described above of color masking / edge detection / region determination through color selection, you should obtain a much better and (arguably) very accurate result.

**The downside to this, is that you're also limited by the image quality used. But, as it's software, that shouldn't be much of an issue, and you can get extremely high accuracy - close to its actual result.**

The last suggestion to improve these results would be to script numerous random thin slicing of the AutoCAD model along a particular directional vector shared by every subsequent slice, exporting each exposed surface, analyzing each image in the manner described above, and then collecting those results to given you a Monte Carlo-like and statistically quantifiable determination of the mass (to correct for geometry effects due to slicing along one given axis).